# Why does jQuery interpret broken markup differently than the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, markup

I have previously answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19101905/1253312), but I do not fully understand *why* the answer is correct. The gist of the answer:

> ```
> <p id="jqrender"></p>
>
> $(function() {
>     $('#jqrender').html("<a href=http://www.website.com/>foo bar</a>");
> });
> ```

On latest Chrome on OSX, jQuery interprets this as `<a href="website.com"></a>foo bar`. Which makes sense, I guess, because it thinks the closest markup correction is `<a href="website" />`. But natively, Chrome itself will interpret the markup as `<a href="website.com/">foo bar</a>`.

**Why is this?** I would like a technical answer, what part of jQuery is doing this markup-fixing, what are some general rules it follows, and how can I guess how jQuery will react to other broken markup?

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.buildFragment

Comment: I think it essentially translates `.html("string")` to `.html($("string"))`. And HTML's fragment parser tries to be clever in allowing you to supply just opening tags, or things like `<div/>`, and it constructs DOM elements from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending line in jQuery source is here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L222

```
tmp.innerHTML = wrap[ 1 ] + elem.replace( rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>" ) + wrap[ 2 ];
```

Where `rxhtmlTag = /<(?!area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)(([\w:]+)[^>]*)\/>/gi`
and `elem` is the fragment of potentially broken markup.

The result of that `replace` call, for that input, is `<a href=http://www.website.com></a>foo bar</a>`.

The browser then does the work of fixing *that* markup, by removing the ultimate `</a>`.

So the other point in the question can be answered with: This particular case will also affect all tags except area, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, link, meta, and param.

tl;dr: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1253312